# still need help centering a div on a wordpress page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, center

I can do percentages of left margin easy, but I can't get this div to center no matter what method I use.

Check it out here: http://www.fahrenheit-hvac.com/thank-you/

I'm trying to get the social div I created to center so as to remain responsive, but all of the solutions I've found online don't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Jason C.

Comment: are you talking about when the website is less than 770px wide?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#socialInPage {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
#socialInPage a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I like this one a little better. By doing this, the responsiveness of the site is maintained. By defining the size like the one above, I noticed that in mobile mode the icons were still a little left, but with this one, they are dead center. Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set a `width` on the containing div (div#socialInPage). I used `275px`, and it seemed to work. Then set the left and right margins to auto.

```
width: 275px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

So long as the `text-align` of parent elements is set to `center`, then this method will center elements on your page.

Comment: this worked...I tried to do a 100% width and it didn't work, but once I defined the width, it does.